# How to extend a TS interface with a type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I'm trying to declare types in TSX. What I would like to have is that if user adds one prop to a component, they can't put the other prop. This works, but I'm using these props in mostly all my components, so I'd like not to repeat this code.

I tried to extend one of my component interface with this type, but I get this error:

```
An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members.
```

How could I do?

This is my code:

```
interface PossibleColors1 {
    color?: AllColorsTypes // List of colors
    customColor?: never
}

interface PossibleColors2 {
    color?: never
    customColor?: CustomColorTypes // Any other color
}

type PossibleColorsTypes = PossibleColors1 | PossibleColors2

interface Props extends PossibleColorsTypes { // This is the line not working
    
}
```

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intersect `PossibleColorsTypes` with another type instead of extending it with an interface:

```
interface PossibleColors1 {
    color?: AllColorsTypes // List of colors
    customColor?: never
}

interface PossibleColors2 {
    color?: never
    customColor?: CustomColorTypes // Any other color
}

type PossibleColorsTypes = PossibleColors1 | PossibleColors2

type Props = PossibleColorsTypes & { myNewProperty: "yay" };
```